# Help needed with 2 node setup

Tags: config, performance, install, craft-pro

I am setting up 2 node cluster with GlusterFS for shared file system. I have mounted the shared mount on each of the nodes but when I try to access login page I get this

/data/websites/websiteapp/craft/storage/ doesn't exist or isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that.

The folder permissions are lrwxrwxrwrx. Is there anything I need to do make it work?

Comment: If you write a simple PHP script outside of Craft that tries to write a file to `/data/websites/websiteapp/craft/storage/` and execute that from a browser, does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the issue, it is related to Ubuntu and how the mount process works using Upstart. I had a line in fstab to load the network drive but Ubuntu fails. Because of that failure, craft couldn't find the shared path which points to craft/storage/